# Why is the product of two tridiagonal matrix is a pentadiagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that the product of two tridiagonal matrix results in a pentadiagonal matrix?

Answer (score 2):

See the following paper: M. Capovani. Su alcune proprietà delle matrici tridiagonali e pentadiagonali.

[Su alcune proprietà delle matrici tridiagonali e pentadiagonali.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02575581)

Capovani proves that the inverse of a nonsymmetric tridiagonal matrix with the super and subdiagonal elements different from zero, also has as inverse a generator representable matrix, where the upper and lower triangular part have different generators. Using these results the author proves that a pentadiagonal matrix can be written as the product of two tridiagonal matrices, for which one of them is symmetric.

Comment: Is it true to say that symmetric pentadiagonal matrix can be written as the product of two symmetric tridiagonal matrices?